# mapStateToProps and properties not coming from the stores

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is it a good idea to include properties not coming from the store in `mapStateToProps`?

e.g.

```
const fooBar = () => 'foobar!'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    todos: getVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter),
    fooBar
  }
}
```

Comment: You can do that. You want be notified about when "fooBar" changes, since it's not changed via Redux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is an acceptable use case - however, we might be able to implement this functionality a bit cleaner. For instance, `mapStateToProps` in `react-redux` accepts a second argument, titled `ownProps`, which are the props passed to the container component in question:

Via https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

> `[mapStateToProps(state, [ownProps]): stateProps]` *(Function)*: 
>   ...If ownProps is specified as a second argument, its value will be the
>   props passed to your component, and mapStateToProps will be re-invoked
>   whenever the component receives new props.

So perhaps rather than instantiating `fooBar` inside of your container component, why not pass it as a prop to the component itself, and then access it via `ownProps`?

**Some Other Component**

```
 <MyContainer fooBar={() => alert('foobar!')}
```

**MyContainer**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    todos: getVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter),
    fooBar: ownProps.fooBar
  }
}
```